# Promise inside a sync function never resolves

Tags: asynchronous, promise, resolve

what happens when promise function inside asynchronous function never resolves or rejected ,so inside below save method if both initial if conditions get not satisfied what will happen, it's not giving error,will it wait there forever till response receive?

```
save().then(results=>{

})

save():promise<any>{
  if (conditionA) {
    return http request
  }
  if (conditonB) {
    return http request}
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not mean that there is a promise that never resolves, it just means that your function does not create a promise at all and `.then()` throws an exception when being called on `undefined`. Don't do that.

Comment: yes currently i am doing a bug fixof older code related to this ,and it shows that cannot call then of undefined , that why i wanted to make sure whether this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your promise sometimes returns a promise, then it should always return a promise.  The usual design pattern if you find you don't need to have a promise to return in some code paths is that you just do a `return Promise.resolve()`.  So, keep with your pseudo-code, you'd do something like this:

```
save().then(results=>{

})

save():promise<any>{
  if (conditionA) {
    return request(...);
  } else if (conditonB) {
    return request(...);
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(...);
  }
}
```

You fill in the `...` parts above to make sense for your function.  But, if you sometimes return a promise, then ALWAYS return a promise.  Then, the caller can just consistently use the returned promise.  If the work is already done (or there was nothing to do), then you just return an already resolved promise and the caller always gets a consistent return value which they can use as a promise.

---

Note, that none of this matches the title of your question, but it does fully match the body of your question.  Is your title just wrong or is there some part of your question description that is missing?

Comment: thank you @jfriend00 
as i mentioned in comments i am fixing some bugs in our existing code and it was saying that "then of undefined error" is occuring 
i thought that because else is not there and promise is not resolving so error occurs ,
but as in reply comments i understood that it's promise not created and not a case with resolving

Comment: @Heshan - Just so others who come along later are not confused, I'd suggest you use the "edit" link under your question and modify the title of your question to better fit what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer should be ,save() cannot be undefined if any kind of promise is returned from the method including the service call(http call),
if it never resolves it will never go into then part of the handler ,but it cannot give the error undefined.
undefined error can be given when no condition satisfied in the if else conditions and nothing returns.